# Сформировать изображения JPG на PHP

Tags: php, изображения, gd

**Дано**: файлы форматов jpg (jpeg) и png разных размеров (небольшие, порядка 300Кб максимум).

**Требуется**: сформировать изображения, соблюдая пропорции, размером 110х110, и поместить на белый фон размером 120х120 (чтобы хоть какой-то минимальный отступ был).

**Попытки реализации**:

1. ***Без проверки на тип данных***:

   ```
   public static function imageResize($out,$in,$weight,$height,$quality) {

       $im=imagecreatefromjpeg($in);
       $im1=imagecreatetruecolor($weight,$height);
       imagecopyresampled($im1,$im,0,0,0,0,$weight,$height,imagesx($im),imagesy($im));

       imagejpeg($im1,$out,$quality);
       imagedestroy($im);
       imagedestroy($im1);
   }

   ...

   $path=$rootPath."/1c/img/".$product->image;
   $realImage=$rootPath."/products/".$product->image;

   ...

   helper::imageresize($realImage,$path,120,120,100);
   ```

*Проблемы*: ругается на png (я ж не проверяю формат), выходные изображения непропорциональны, изображения из png создаются просто черными.

2. ***С проверкой, но без пропорций***:

   ```
   public static function getImage($path){
       $mime = mime_content_type($path);
       switch($mime) {
           case 'image/png':
               $img = imagecreatefrompng($path);
               break;
           case 'image/gif':
               $img = imagecreatefromgif($path);
               break;
           case 'image/jpeg':
               $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
               break;
           default:
               $img = null;
       }
       return $img;
   }

   ...

   $realImage=$rootPath."/products/".$product->image;

   ...

   $gdImage=helper::getImage($path);
   $im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 120);
   imagejpeg($gdImage, $realImage);
   imagedestroy($gdImage);
   ```

*Проблемы*: изображения просто копируются одно в другое (с исходными размерами), изображения из png скопировались, но встали на черном фоне.

То есть, в первом случае, я работаю с реальными изображениями, а во втором с объектами, и как объединить оба способа я не знаю. К тому же требуется еще создать пустое белое изображение и поместить на него пропорциональное подготовленное изображение.
Также **очень важно**, чтобы конечные jpg файлы были именно jpg, чтобы потом, при последующем копировании, я не делал проверки на тип данных (мне потом это все через PHPExcel размещать в файле нужно будет (но там уже все готово)).

**P.S.** За многоточиями опущено получение записей из БД и цикл, в котором выполняется этот код.

**P.P.S.** @teran, огромное спасибо! Вот что получилось, благодаря Вашим наводкам, может кому и пригодится (комментарии просто для пояснения):

```
public static function imageResize($out,$in,$width,$height,$quality) {
    //создаем новое изображение из входного с проверкой типа файла
    $im=self::getImage($in);

    //создаем новое пустое изображение, заданных размеров
    $im1=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);

    //заполняем только что созданное изображение
    //белым цветом (по умолчанию создается с черным фоном)
    imagefill($im1,0,0,imagecolorallocate($im1, 255, 255, 255));

    //копируем входное изображение в только что созданное и покрашенное с
    //сохранением пропорций (сильно не пинайте, как понял, так и написал)
    imagecopyresampled($im1,$im,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,imagesx($im),imagesy($im));

    //создаем новое JPG изображение и удаляем экземпляры,
    //с которыми работали в памяти
    imagejpeg($im1,$out,$quality);
    imagedestroy($im);
    imagedestroy($im1);
}
```

**P.P.P.S.** Сделал как сумел, может есть более правильные решения данной задачи? Единственное с чем несправился так это с добавлением бордюров по краям изображения, то есть ужать исходник до 110х110 и поместить на холст в 120х120, правда изображения итак мелкие, но может пригодится в будущем.

Comment: и что, вы в первом коде вместо `imagecreatefromjpeg` не можете вызвать свой второй `getImage`?

Comment: @teran пока не пробовал, к тому же я не знаю, как png сделать белый фон

Comment: вроде тоже дело не хитрое [`imagefill()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagefill.php)

Comment: @teran спасибо за наводку, попробую прогнать изображения через серию преобразований))